# Find the MLE of $\theta=(\alpha,\beta)$ and its asymptotic distribution.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, poisson-distribution, maximum-likelihood

> Let $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ be indepedendent and Poisson random variables with $E(Y_i)=\exp(\alpha+\beta z_i)$. Find the MLE of $\theta=(\alpha,\beta)$ and its asymptotic distribution.

Question:  It is not easy to find the MLE directly. It seems that it is a hierarchical model.

For the asymptotic distribution. It seems that the delta method may be applied.

Can anyone give some hint? Especially, how to calculate the MLE?

I thought $Y|\bigwedge$~$Poisson (\bigwedge)$

$\bigwedge$~$Exp(\alpha+\beta Z)$

Thus,

$f_Y(y)=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{z^y e^{-z}}{y!} e^{(\alpha+\beta z)}dz|$

Though  I can not make sure whether $Exp(\alpha+\beta Z)$ is a distribution

and how to calculate $f_Y(y)$Many thanks!

Comment: would you like to share what you did? just under the question.

Comment: Do you know both the $z_i$ and the observed $Y_i$?